# How can you work out the data Type from a generic Class?

Tags: vb.net

How can you work out the data Type from a generic Class?

Example:

```
 Sub doWork(ObType As System.Type)
  Select Case ObType
   Case GetType(MyClass1)
    'do stuff
   Case GetType(MyClass2)
    'do stuff
   Case GetType(MyClass3(of T)
    'do stuf
  End Select
 End Sub
```

Working out if the `ObType` is a `Myclass1` or `MyClass2` seems to be working fine, but how do i work out `MyClass3`, i'm not concerned what T is.

Comment: Since you arent passing the object, just it's Type, you dont need/cant use the object, so you could just as easily pass a string or Enum indicating what to to.  Or overload the sub,

Comment: unfortunately i can't as i'm using Reflection to get the datatype to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems this is the way:

```
If ObType.IsGenericType andalso ObType.GetGenericTypeDefinition = GetType(MyClass3(Of )) Then
'do work
End If
```